# Changing diagram notation to UML in Visual Paradigm

Tags: uml, erd

I have drawn an ER Diagram in Visual Paradigm (DBVA Software) for my database.

As i know, Viusal Paradigm uses **Crow's Foot** notation for showing ERD objects.

Is there any way to convert my ER diagram to **UML** notation in DBVA?

[Here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/ERD_Representation.svg) you can see **Crow's Foot** and **UML** notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed this tutorial and it seems to be what you need.  You Sync the ER Diagram with a UML Class diagram etc.

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/dbva/tutorials/generatecdfromerd.jsp